# Allow Servlet Access only via jsp pages; not directly

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I have a servlet where it will connect to db and give response. It will be called inside another jsp pages via ajax call.

But if the user knows the servlet path they can hit my servlet from the browser directly . My requirement is I want to allow them to reach my servlet only via ajax not directly. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If the call to the servlet is done via Ajax, it means that the user is already calling it using direct HTTP requests to invoke it.

You cannot restrict an enterprising user to not figure out what URL he could call directly and which parameters to append to get favourable results.

You could try to look at referrer headers, but those can be faked as well.

Your application must not depend on the users not messing with the request patterns (or their cookies or your Javascript) for anything security-relevant. Do not trust any user input blindly, validate everything (against server-side state that cannot be tampered with).

That is just the nature of client-server programming (expecially with such an open-box client as a web browser over a global network such as the public Internet).